# Couldn't find Post without an ID in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In **show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :comment, :url=> {:controller => 'comments', :action => 'create'} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id , :value => @post.id %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

in **Comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
  if @comments.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    redirect_to post_path
  end
end
```

In **Routes.rb**
resources :posts

```
match '/create',  :to => 'comments#create'  , :as => :create
```

when i add any comment from view form it gives following error :

```
'Couldn't find Post without an ID'
```

i cant figure out why params[:id] not returning Post ID ?
Note : I am using acts_as_commentable

Comment: You can always see the incoming `params` by raising them in your controller action like so: `raise params.inspect` or `raise params.to_yaml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer

**comments_controller** should be as

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:comment][:id])    
    @comments = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    if @comments.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      redirect_to post_path
    end
  end
end
```

> @post = Post.find(params[:comment][:id])

Answer (score 3):

The reason your params[:id] not returning Post ID because in your `routes.rb` you choose url `/create`, in which you have not specified any placeholder for `id`.

if you want something like `params[:id]` then in your `routes.rb` you should write `'/create/:id'` in `match` mathod.